# Getting the current user id and storing it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am currently trying to make an Up Vote/ Down Vote system on my webapp (on my comments, very similar to StackOverflow).  I can currently add and subtract votes, but I don't have a validation in place to limit the amount of up and down votes per user.

Furthermore, I think the key to my problem is getting the current user id.  My front end is built on backbone and backend is on rails.  In rails and in erb, I can use current_user to get the current_user id (I think current_user comes from devise).  The problem is my voting system still isn't storing a user's id that voted.

I think I have to add an "upvote_id" column to my data table.  Here is my current table.

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id" **the user that created the comment
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "upvotes"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

In backbone, this is my upvote/downvote functions and events.** addUpVote, **removeUpVote

```
app.CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: 'div',

  template: _.template( $('#comment-template').html() ),

  // "<event> <selector>" : "<method>" aka function defined below
  events: {
    // 'keypress #new-comment': 'createNewCommentOnEnter',
    'click #up' : 'addUpVote',
    'click #down' :'subtractVote',
    // 'click #comment-field' : 'toggleCommentField'
    'click .destroy_comment' : 'removeOneComment'

  },

  initialize: function() {
    // this.listenTo(this.model, 'add', this.addOneComment);
    this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    // this.$el.attr('comment_id', this.model.get('id'));
    this.$input = this.$('#new-comment');
    this.$upvote = this.$('#upvote');
    return this;
  },

removeOneComment: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
  },

  addUpVote: function() {
    console.log(this.model);
    var upVoteCount = this.model.get('upvotes');
    var newUpVoteCount = upVoteCount + 1;
    console.log(newUpVoteCount);
      this.model.save({upvotes: newUpVoteCount});
  },

  subtractVote: function() {
    var downVoteCount = this.model.get('upvotes');
    var newDownVoteCount = downVoteCount - 1;
      this.model.save({upvotes: newDownVoteCount});
  }
```

One way I can think of solving my problem is being able to get the current user id as they click up vote or down vote.  Then, take the user_id of the voter and store it in my comments table in a new column called upVotersId.  Then with that ID I can start creating validations.

Is this a reasonable approach?  I am unclear on how to get the current user id, maybe I can get it from the click event? I want to gather any user_id that clicks on the upvote arrow or the downvote arrow to limit the amount of times they can click (if their id is in the upVotersId field, they can no longer vote).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can gather/get the upvoters user id?

Sorry if I did not post enough information to solve the problem.  I'll add my user table as well.  Thanks for the help!

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                              default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",                 default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "question_id",            limit: 255
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                      default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the proper design that suites your problem is:

1. Create a `User` Backbone.Model that will be instantiated upon login
2. The `User` Model should be accessible from you `CommentView`
3. In the `Comment` Model instead of upvote/downvote have a `VotingDictionary` (simple json) object  from User->Vote, for example:
   `{
    12333326 : +1, 
    23132234 : -1 
   }`
4. Have 2 function in the `Comment` model, model.upvote(id) and model.downvote(id) that manipulate this `VotingDictionary`
5. When a the user clicks the the upVote button you should call in the view `this.model.upvote(user.get("userID"))`
6. The Comments view calculates the voting score upon and updates the html with the view
7. The Comments is saved on and server (via rest api) if something fails, it should be rollbacked with the proper user notification

**NOTE**: You shouldn't use html element id (`<div id='upvote'>`) if you have more then one element with this id in the HTML page (many comments) you should use class instead